# How to change the href for a hyperlink in head using jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

When user clicks navigation tab (for ex. "News" (code is in layout/navigation.html)), href in head must automatically change to href="../style.css"

[image: My folders structure]

### snippet of head.html

```
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){     
    $(".nav li a").click(function(){   
     $("head link").each(function() {
      if ($(this).attr("type")=="text/css"){
      var link=$(this).attr("href");
      alert(link);//OK
      $(this).attr("href","../"+link);//not working
     }
      }); 
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: do you want this https://jsfiddle.net/eL0ag27d/

Comment: I got answer. Thanks.